# Is there a way to instrument Web/Javascript/ReactJS client for AWS X-Ray?

Tags: aws-xray, x-ray

We are trying to see if we can collect performance as seen by Web application users (single page application using ReactJS, performance numbers that includes the client-to-server network/load time along with the back-end/DB server performance). I could not find any client side JS API examples for X-Ray . Is there one?

Ideally we are looking for performance data collection similar to NewRelic products.  Thank you!

DS

Answer (score 0):

Currently X-Ray do not have capability to collect Client side statistics. X-Ray is looking into ways to support this usecase but do not have ETA on when.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please provide a link to back up what you are saying?